# RabbitMQ: ACCESS_REFUSED even if the queue is non-exclusive

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to send and receive messages between two computers via RabbitMQ in C++. My sender code looks like this:

```
AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t channel = AmqpClient::Channel::Create("192.168.1.1", 5672, "test", "test", "/");
channel->DeclareQueue("rabbit", false, true, false, false);
AmqpClient::BasicMessage::ptr_t msg = AmqpClient::BasicMessage::Create("Hello Rabbit!");
channel->BasicPublish("", "rabbit", msg);
std::cout << "[x] message sent!" << std::endl;
```

My receiver code on another computer with `192.168.1.1` ip address looks like this:

```
AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t connection = AmqpClient::Channel::Create("localhost", 5672, "test", "test", "/");
connection->DeclareQueue("rabbit", false, true, false, false);

std::string consumer = connection->BasicConsume("rabbit", "", true, false);
while(true)
{
    AmqpClient::Envelope::ptr_t envelope = connection->BasicConsumeMessage(consumer);
    std::cout << "received message: " << envelope->Message()->Body() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[x] ready to receive new message..." << std::endl;
    connection->BasicAck(envelope);
}
```

This works quite fine when the receiver starts to receive AFTER the sender code finishes and terminates. But when I first open the receiver to let it stand by and send message, on the sender side, I receive the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'AmqpClient::AccessRefusedException'
  what(): channel error: 403: AMQP_BASIC_CONSUME_METHOD caused: ACCESS_REFUSED - queue 'rabbit' in vhost '/' in exclusive use
```

I know this error should raise when the declared queue is in exclusive mode, but here I declared it as non-exclusive (the third boolean parameter in `channel->DeclareQueue`). Also, my test user has full privilege. What could be the problem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the default value for `BasicConsume` is `exclusive`, so it is important to let it be `false` when declaring your consumer as follows (the third boolean param):

```
std::string consumer = connection->BasicConsume("rabbit", "", true, false, false);
                                                                           ^^^^^
```

Interestingly, I didn't find any sentence about this on official documentation.